# del x[n] not working

Tags: python, del

I have a list and I am trying to remove the first item in it

I have tried to use this code, but it doesn't do anything

```
del rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9].split()[0]
```

for context

```
rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9].split()
```

finds an item in a list which is a string then splits the string into a list, this string is

```
Skyfall Skyfall DarkKnight DieHard  CaptainAmerica Deadpool TheMatrix CaptainAmerica TheMatrix  CaptainAmerica TheBourneIdentity
```

Comment: what do you *expect* it to do?

Comment: It works fine. It creates a list by splitting the string, deletes the first item, then throws the list away.

Comment: You are simply deleting the first element of a list which is immediately discarded...

Comment: sorry I didn't make it more clear, I will edit this into the post, but the result doesn't actually remove the first item, it just stays the same

Comment: @MatthewPearson Try: `xs = rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9].split(); del xs[0]; print(xs)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pop()` or index it out with slicing like this:

```
rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9] = " ".join(rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9].split().pop())
```

or

```
rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9] = " ".join(rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9].split()[1:])
```

Comment: Perfect, I did have a feeling that " ".join should be used, however I couldn't think of how to practically use this, but it makes much more sense now, thanks!

Comment: Wow, how did you guess, he wanted to join it again?

Comment: Since his example only references the 10th element of the sublist, I guessed that main list (`rows`) is composed of homogeneous sublist and that it wouldn't make sense to have a mixture of strings and list when referencing the 10th element of any given sublist later on if the reference is a random(ish) or even repeat event.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
lst = rows[rows.index(userInfo)][9].split()
del lst[0]
```

When you do it in a single line, you are not saving the list created by `split()`, so deleting an element from the anonymous list has no practical effect. If you assign the list to a variable first, you can delete the first element with `del` and then act on the list as you please.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you try to delete something from a list that is not persistent.
`....split()` returns a list from which you try to delete an element. But this list is not stored.
You need at least two lines:

```
mylist = ....split()
del mylist[0]
```

As `split()` does not work inplace, you need to store it anyway...
So you could also write:

```
mylist = foo.split()[1:]
```